# adding a column which derive from another column by an expression with awk

Tags: awk

How can I add a column after first, which has values calculate from an expression. this expression has a form: (vn+v0)*vl where v0 and vl is the first and last element of 3th column, respectively and vn is nth element of that column. for example we have a text table:

```
1 2 3 4
10 20 30 40 
100 200 300 400
```

it should be converted to

```
1  1800 3 4
10  9900 30 40 
100 180000 300 400
```

thanks

Comment: can you explain how you get to `180000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the rule you defined in your question, the number in the last line should not be `180000`. it should be  `(300+3)*300=90900`

this awk line could work for you:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{c[NR]=$3;l=NR;next}{$2=($3+c[1])*c[l]}7' file file
```

output is:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{c[NR]=$3;l=NR;next}{$2=($3+c[1])*c[l]}7' file file
1 1800 3 4
10 9900 30 40
100 90900 300 400
```

**EDIT**

OP wants add a new column after the first:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{c[NR]=$3;l=NR;next}{$2=($3+c[1])*c[l]" "$2}7' file file
1 1800 2 3 4
10 9900 20 30 40
100 90900 200 300 400
```

Comment: I used above commands but it substitutes the 2nd column instead of adding. How to solve it?

Comment: @Atoof the awk line gives same output as your expected result in you question. Pls double check it. If you want to "add", you should let us know where to add. Edit your question first!

Comment: @Atoof see EDIT, add a new column after the 1st.

Comment: How can I do above when I have multiple .dat files?